# Como capturar o innerHTML de um documentFragment via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5, documentfragment

O `documentFragment`que é criado utilizando o método `document.createDocumentFragment()` não contém as propriedades `innerHTML` e `outerHTML` igual elementos derivados de `HTMLElement` tem.

Mas preciso pegar o conteúdo do fragmento em formato de string. Porém não posso simplesmente dar um `appendChild` do fragmento em outro elemento pra ter o `innerHTML`, pois isso deixaria a instancia do fragmento vazia uma vez que seu conteúdo seria transportado pra outro elemento.

Preciso extrair o HTML em forma de string do fragmento sem alterá-lo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use apenas: `frag.querySelector('*').innerHTML`

O asterísco seleciona qualquer primeiro objeto DOM achado dentro do fragmento, que no caso é a raiz, e ai então, com o objeto DOM raiz nas mãos é possível usar `innerHTML`, ou o `outerHTML` se for o caso.

**EDIT**

No caso de seu fragmento conter múltiplos elementos raízes, então use `querySelectorAll`:

```
var conteudo = "";
var all = frag.querySelectorAll('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++)
        if (!all[i].parentElement)
            conteudo += all[i].outerHTML;

// mostrando o output na página
$("#output").text($("#output").text() + conteudo);
```

querySelectorAll é bem suportado nos browsers:
http://caniuse.com/queryselector

**EDIT 2:** Uma solução mais performática usando `querySelector` ao invés de `querySelectorAll`:

```
var conteudo = "";
var current = frag.querySelector('*');
while (current) {
    conteudo += current.outerHTML + "\n";
    current = current.nextSibling;
}
```

**EDIT 3:** como as opções anteriores não funcionaram no IE8, continuei procurando até achar a seguinte alternativa (que funciona em todos os browsers que eu testei):

```
var conteudo = "";
var rootNodes = frag.childNodes;
for (var i = 0; i < rootNodes.length; i++)
    conteudo += rootNodes[i].outerHTML;
```

Comment: Atualizei a resposta para múltiplos elementos raízes.

Comment: `querySelectorAll` garante a ordem dos elementos? Pq se ele garantir provavelmente essa solução esta solução serve ao meu propósito.

Comment: Poxa vida, ele está selecionando também os filhos... vou ver se tem como selecionar só os elementos raiz sem os filhos.

Comment: Miguel acho que se juntar a sua resposta com o bfavaretto, seria a solução mais correta, agora não sei pra quem dar como solução da questão...

Comment: Acho que `querySelectorAll('*')` vai pegar todos os elementos dentro do fragment, não só as raízes.

Comment: Código corrigido, agora só as raízes serão selecionadas.

Comment: Eu excluí os não raízes manualmente, dentro do for... não sei se isso é bom para performance.

Comment: Agora sim, uma solução que não é ruim de performance: usar `querySelector('*')` e depois usar `nextSibling` e ir concatenando o outerHTML. Dessa forma, inclusive, a ordenação fica mais garantida... é a ordem de inserção dos elementos no fragmento.

Comment: Milésima edição... =) Foi mal por tantas edições pessoal.

Comment: Obrigado Miguel, realmente a ultima foi a mesma coisa que eu acabei fazendo pra resolver esse caso, então a resposta está correta, o legal das edições é que ficou uma base de conhecimento para os proximos que tiverem esta mesma dúvida. =) Novamente obrigado!

Comment: O método do edit 2 é bem eficiente, 3x mais rápido que o meu: http://jsperf.com/documentfragment-innerhtml

Answer (score 1):

Considerando seus requisitos, parece que a única maneira seria clonar cada filho do fragmento:

```
function fragHtml(frag) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    for(var i=0; i<frag.children.length; i++) {
        div.appendChild(frag.children[i].cloneNode(true));
    }
    return div.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Bem interessante, mas acho que pra pegar a string, a melhor solução deve ser a junção da sua resposta com a do Miguel Angelo, pois a sua solução mantém a ordem dos elementos correta, só não precisaria clonar todos elementos pra pegar sua string...

Answer (score 1):

A [MDN refere](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment.querySelector) o método:

> element = documentframgment.querySelector(selectors);

Assim, um exemplo seria:

HTML

```
<div id="test" contenteditable="true">
    Teste
    <img src="/favicon.png" alt=""/>
</div>
```

JS

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var teste = document.getElementById('test');
frag.appendChild(teste);
console.log(frag);       // #document-fragment
var conteudo = frag.querySelector('#test');
console.log(conteudo.innerHTML);   //  Teste<img src="/favicon.png" alt="">
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/XGh5A/)

Answer (score -2):

Uma sugestão seria mapear os nós e convertê-los para string:

```js
function getFragmentHTML(fragment) {
  return Array.from(fragment.childNodes).map(item => item.innerHTML).join('');
}
```

Isso vai pegar todos os nós de um fragment, transformar em um array comum, converter cada entrada para o equivalente ao conteúdo html do item corrente, e retornar isso concatenado em uma string única. Como utilizamos childNodes, TEXT_NODES serão preservados, preservando assim a formatação original tbm.

Comment: Não votei na sua resposta, mas posso explicar os negativos. Quando a pergunta e essas respostas foram escritas não existiam o elemento HTM [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) que encapsula um `documentFragment` veja esse exemplo https://codepen.io/AugustoVasques/pen/mdoxRMB . Atualmente tanto o sua resposta e as outras são aproveitáveis apenas para o Opera Mini e IE, mas já existem polyfill do elemento DOM `HTMLTemplate` para esses navegadores.